# MySQL reads / writes per table

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am optimising our DB. Essentially I am trying to find the most written and the most read tables in our db. After that I will follow by sym-linking those tables into separate drives.

Is there a way of following each tables activity ?
As in follow IOPS, writes, reads per table ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Method 1**

If you are using [Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/) or [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/) (>= 5.2), you can simply set the [userstat/userstat_running](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-server:features:userstatv2) variable to enable a bunch of new INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables including one called TABLE_STATISTICS that provides exactly this information.

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, ROWS_READ, ROWS_CHANGED, ROWS_CHANGED_X_INDEXES FROM TABLE_STATISTICS ORDER BY ROWS_CHANGED DESC LIMIT 5;
+-------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME        | ROWS_READ  | ROWS_CHANGED | ROWS_CHANGED_X_INDEXES |
+-------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| user              |   21122527 |      5989231 |               23956924 |
| audit             |       1208 |      5020929 |               20083716 |
| sometemp          |   13995426 |      3182150 |                9546450 |
| creditcards       |    3566482 |      2998976 |               11995904 |
| order             | 2147483647 |      2662606 |               53252120 |
+-------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

ROWS_CHANGED would correspond to the most written to tables and ROWS_READ would be the most read from.  You should also look at INDEX_STATISTICS to find your most and least used indexes.

See also the [MariaDB user statistics documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user-statistics/).

**Method 2**

If you are not using Percona Server, you could use [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-query-digest.html) to capture a sample of your queries and then filter out only INSERT/UPDATE/DELETEs.  That would look something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.slow_query_log_file;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.slow_query_log_file             |
+------------------------------------------+
| /var/logs/mysql/slowquery.log            |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file='/tmp/allqueries.log';
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.long_query_time;
+--------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.long_query_time |
+--------------------------+
|                 0.250000 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 0;
mysql> FLUSH LOGS;
mysql> SLEEP 600; SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 0.25; SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file='/var/logs/mysql/slowquery.log'; FLUSH LOGS;
```

Now you have a file, `/tmp/allqueries.log` that contains every query executed on your server for ~10 minutes.

Next, analyze it with pt-query-digest to get the most frequently written to tables:

```
pt-query-digest /tmp/allqueries.log --group-by=distill --filter '$event->{arg} =~ m/^(update|delete|insert)/i' --limit 5 > /tmp/writes.txt
```

If you examine `/tmp/writes.txt`, you will see a section near the top that looks like this:

```
# Profile
# Rank Query ID Response time Calls R/Call Apdx V/M   Item
# ==== ======== ============= ===== ====== ==== ===== ====================
#    1 0x        0.0558 26.8%   282 0.0002 1.00  0.00 INSERT UPDATE user
#    2 0x        0.0448 21.5%   246 0.0002 1.00  0.00 UPDATE audit
#    3 0x        0.0228 10.9%    11 0.0021 1.00  0.00 UPDATE sometemp
#    4 0x        0.0108  5.2%    16 0.0007 1.00  0.00 UPDATE creditcards
#    5 0x        0.0103  4.9%    43 0.0002 1.00  0.00 UPDATE order
```

Roughly, these are your most written to tables for the duration of the sample you chose.  To get the most read from tables (roughly), you can change the `--filter` parameter to `--filter '$event->{arg} =~ m/^select/i'` and you will see similar output.

If you are only interested in writes, you can pass a binary log into `pt-query-digest` and get similar results:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000511 | pt-query-digest --type=binlog --group-by=distill > /tmp/writes.txt
```

You can also get the same data with tcpdump and `pt-query-digest --type=tcpdump`

So, this being said, assuming that you are using InnoDB tables, I highly doubt that you will see much performance benefit from doing this at all.  Because of the way data is buffered to the InnoDB log and then written to disk, I wouldn't expect much or any performance gain from moving individual tables around like this.  You *might* see some benefit from moving the InnoDB log files themselves to separate, faster disk to separate the log read/writes from the tablespace read/writes, but even that is questionable.  Investing in fast, high quality RAID arrays with a battery backed cache (or better yet, SSD) will be a better use of your resources.

Comment: battery backed cache - Could you give me some link to look further into those ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID would be a good place to start.  RAID10 is generally superior to RAID5 or 6 for databases.